# Testing FastAPI FormData Upload

Tags: python, upload, fastapi

I'm trying to test the upload of a file and its metadata using **Python** and **FastAPI**.

Here is how I defined the route for the upload:

```
@app.post("/upload_files")
async def creste_upload_files(uploaded_files: List[UploadFile], selectedModel: str = Form(...),
                              patientId: str = Form(...), patientSex: str = Form(...),
                              actualMedication: str = Form(...), imageDim: str = Form(...),
                              imageFormat: str = Form(...), dateOfScan: str = Form(...)):
    for uploaded_dicom in uploaded_files:
        upload_folder = "webapp/src/data/"
        file_object = uploaded_dicom.file
        #create empty file to copy the file_object to
        upload_folder = open(os.path.join(upload_folder, uploaded_dicom.filename), 'wb+')
        shutil.copyfileobj(file_object, upload_folder)
        upload_folder.close()
    return "hello"
```

(I'm not using the metadata but I will later).

I use unittest for the testing:

```
class TestServer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = TestClient(app)
        self.metadata = {
            "patientId": "1",
            "patient_age": "M",
            "patientSex": "59",
            "patient_description": "test",
            "actualeMedication": "test",
            "dateOfScan": datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%d/%m/%Y"),
            "selectedModel": "unet",
            "imageDim": "h",
            "imageFormat": "h"
        }

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_dcm_upload(self):
        dicom_file = pydicom.read_file("tests/data/1-001.dcm")
        bytes_data = dicom_file.PixelData
   
        files = {"uploaded_files": ("dicom_file", bytes_data, "multipart/form-data")}
        response = self.client.post(
            "/upload_files",
            json=self.metadata,
            files=files
        )
        print(response.json())
```

But it seems that the upload doesn't work, I get the following print of the *response*:

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'selectedModel'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ['body', 'patientId'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ['body', 'patientSex'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ['body', 'actualMedication'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ['body', 'imageDim'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ['body', 'imageFormat'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}, {'loc': ['body', 'dateOfScan'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

It is possible that I should upload using a Formdata instead of the body request (`json=self.metadata`) but I don't know how it should be done.

Comment: I also want to test with formData, have you found any method? I am trying but no lib supporting that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is just to replace `json=self.metadata` which can be used for body parameters by `data=self.metadata` for a formData